# Use specific version of package per directory with Homebrew on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, homebrew

I often find myself switching to a specific version of a package installed with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) when switching projects.

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/projects/project1
$ brew switch phantomjs 2.0.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.7_1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.8
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.0.0
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.0.0
```

And then when changing project:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/projects/project2
$ brew switch phantomjs 1.9.8
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.7_1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.8
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.0.0
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.8
```

Is it somehow possible to automate this so that I can force `brew` to automatically switch to a specified version when inside a certain project?

Would be nice if one could create a file called something like `.homebrew`inside the target directory and from there specify required packages and versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: take a look at [ondir](https://github.com/alecthomas/ondir). I have not personally used it, but it appears to fit your use case.

> ondir is a small program to automate tasks specific to certain directories. It works by executing scripts in directories when you enter and leave them.

To ruminate for a moment, though...

Swapping out package versions on enter/exit of dirs via the shell is, well, risky for a variety of reasons. (For starters, think about two terminal sessions, each in their own dir.)

What you're asking for (per-dir homebrew config) is effectively a virtual machine or container, since it goes beyond "virtualizing" a language (ex: Ruby via [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), Python via [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/)`) and instead is for all system packages. You should consider setting up a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) box for your projects to properly isolate them from your Mac and manage your dependencies better.

Anyway, back to your problem at hand...

PhantomJS is a standalone tool that happens to be helpfully available as a [statically linked binary](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads). We can use this to our advantage. Instead of swapping PhantomJS versions via `brew switch`, just download each statically linked version, stick the binary in `~/bin`, name it appropriately (e.g. `phantomjs-1.9.8`), and adjust your scripts to call the desired version. If you can't adjust the scripts, you'll need to devise another scheme (project-specific symlinks, etc.)

Or, as suggested in [your query on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/39432%23issuecomment-99342198), you could also adjust your `PATH`, either via `ondir` or a wrapping script around whatever drives `phantomjs`.

(Yes, for the [second time in one night](https://superuser.com/a/916983/327091) I pointed someone to a tool I have not personally used.)