# Is there a folder-specific .bashrc or .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, shell-script

Is it possible to have a bash script (like a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, basically) that is executed only upon cd’ing into a specific folder?

Comment: Not yet. But you could alias `cd` to read one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`.

If `.bashrc` is located in current working directory:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$bashrc" != "$PWD" && "$PWD" != "$HOME" && -e .bashrc ]]; then bashrc="$PWD"; . .bashrc; fi'
```

Comment: can you explain how this works...please? :)

Comment: If variable $PROMPT_COMMAND is set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt. In this case it makes three tests before .bashrc in current working directory is sourced.

Comment: This seemed to break my bash config, after adding this line to my `~/.bashrc` file, upon opening a new terminal window my prompt and all my bashrc config in my home dir bashrc wasn't applied (I got the default prompt, etc).

Comment: Although this works it also pollutes your bash process with (exported) variables, aliases and functions that you might not want to keep around when changing to a different directory. I spent some time solving that by spawning a new bash process when a local bashrc is found. See https://github.com/bas080/dotlocaldotbashrc

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact use case and constraints, [ondir](https://github.com/alecthomas/ondir/) may suit your needs:

> ondir is a small program to automate tasks specific to certain directories. It works by executing scripts in directories when you enter and leave them.

It does this by using a central `~/.ondirrc` file for per-dir configuration. In contrast, the clever `PROMPT_COMMAND`  setup that @Cyrus suggested allows for the config to reside in the individual directories themselves. Each approach is valid; it depends on the constraints and data you're dealing with.

**Disclaimer:** I've never used `ondir` personally. I came across it while looking for an automatic way to handle [git user config per-dir](http://makandracards.com/makandra/19549-how-to-set-git-user-and-email-per-directory). In that case, `ondir` didn't fit my needs—I ended up using a git alias passing `--config` options to `git clone`.

Answer (score 0):

addition from @Cyrus answer,
if you use `zsh`, you need to use `precmd()` :

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$profile" != "$PWD" && "$PWD" != "$HOME" && -e .profile ]]; then profile="$PWD"; source .profile; fi'
precmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
```

it's answered from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/735660/whats-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-prompt-command)

**nb:**
my prompt tests for `.profile` not `.bashrc`.